# How do I select one group of values from dataset to plot a linechart using D3.js and not the whole dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
entity,code,year,value
Afghanistan,AFG,1990,10.31850413
Afghanistan,AFG,1991,10.32701045
Albania,ALB,1990,3.985169898
Albania,ALB,1991,4.199006705
```

I want to plot a linechart with D3.js, but only for the country with code "AFG". the x-axis is going to be years from 1990 - 2017, the y-axis is the value. Currently, my code takes all the countries and thus creates a linechart with over a hundred overlapping lines. How do I change this code in order for it to take the specified value:

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 560 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg2 = d3.select("#linechart")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("./files/suicide-death-rates.csv",



  // Now I can use this dataset:
  function(data) {

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }))
      .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg2.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
      .range([ height, 0 ]);
    svg2.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Add the line
    svg2.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.year) })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
        )

})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder if you can use the .filter() to modify your dataset for only AFG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply filter the `.datum(data)` like so:

```
// Add the line
svg2.append("path")
  .datum(data.filter(f => f.code ==="AFG"))
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("d", d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year) })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
    )
```